# Uniform convergence of a sequence of functions $(f_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

This is the exercise problem 6.2.2(a) in Abbott's *Understanding Analysis* text. I'd like someone to verify if my proof is correct. Also, is my exposition clear, or is it over-engineered?

> Define a sequence of functions on $\mathbf{R}$ by
>
> $$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
> 1 & \text{ if } x = 1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots,\frac{1}{n}\\
> 0 & \text{ otherwise }
> \end{cases}$$

Is each $f_n$ continuous at zero? Does $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $\mathbf{R}$? Is $f$ continuous at zero?

***Proof.***

(a) Is each $f_n$ continuous at zero?

Pick an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. Let $N \in \mathbf{N}$ be arbitrary.

Let $(x_k) \to 0$ be an arbitrary convergent sequence. As $(x_k)$ is convergent, there exists K such that $|x_k| < \frac{1}{N}$, for all $k \geq K$.

Immediately, it follows that $f_N(x_k)=0$ for all $k \geq K$. Consequently, the image sequence $f_N(x_k) \to 0$.

As $(x_k)$ was arbitrary, this is true for all sequences approaching zero. By definition, $f_N(x)$ is continuous at zero.

As $N$ was arbitrary, this is true for all $f_n(x)$, where $n \in \mathbf{N}$.

**QED.**

> Although not asked for, I investigate the pointwise convergence of $(f_n)$.

Is $(f_n)$ pointwise convergent to some $f$?

$(f_n)$  is the zero sequence for all $x \neq \frac{1}{n}$, $n \in \mathbf{N}$. Let us explore pointwise convergence at points of the form $x = \frac{1}{n}$ in the interval $(0,1)$.

Pick an arbitrary $N\in \mathbf{N}$  and fix $x = \frac{1}{N}$.

The tail $f_n(x)=1$ for all $n \geq N$. Consequently,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x = \frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbf{N} \\
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

**QED.**

Does $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $\mathbf{R}$?

Let sample the functions $f_n(x)$ at different points.
\begin{align*}
(f_n(1)) &= (1,1,1,1,\ldots)\\
(f_n(\frac{1}{2})) &= (0,1,1,1,\ldots)\\
(f_n(\frac{1}{3})) &= (0,0,1,1,\ldots)\\
(f_n(\frac{1}{4})) &= (0,0,0,1,\ldots)\\
\vdots
\end{align*}

No. Pick $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Let $N \in \mathbf{N}$ be arbitrary. And let $x = \frac{1}{N+1}$.

For $n = N$, we have,

$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = |f_N(x) - f(x)| =|0 - 1| > \epsilon$.

Thus, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ and some points $x \in \mathbf{R}$ such that for all $N \in \mathbf{N}$, $|f_n(x) - f(x)| > \epsilon$ for some $n \geq N$. So, $|f_n(x) - f(x)|>\epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$'s.

That is, $(f_n)$ does not uniformly converge to $f$.

**QED.**

Is $f$ continuous at zero?

No $f$ is not continuous at zero. Pick $(x_n) = 1/n$. Then, as $(x_n) \to 0$, $f(x_n) \to 1$, but $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Why didn't the question define $f$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. You wrote that you were going to investigate the pointwise convergence of $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ “Although not asked for”, but you *had* to study the pointwise convergence of the sequence in order to get the only possible function to which $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ could possibly converge uniformly.

And a minor detail: asserting that $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ meanse that there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for every $N\in\Bbb N$, you have the inequality $|f(x)-f_n(x)|\geqslant\varepsilon$ for some $n\geqslant N$ and for some $x\in\Bbb R$. So, you could have taken $\varepsilon=1$ instead of $\varepsilon=\frac12$.